# Trying to create a formula to calculate a rate value per row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, array

I think this is to do with a formula over an array but I can’t get it to work.

I’m looking for the easiest method to do the following.

Say I have this setup, columns are 'jobs' and rows are 'addresses'

```
|   windows | guttering | cost per house
|  addressA |     3     |        4  
|  addressB |    11     |        7
|      rate |     4     |       10
```

I want the total for a cost per house. So the job * the rate for each job per address. So for above cost per house for `addressA` is  `(3*4) + (4*10)` for address B is (`11*4) + (7*10)` etc… for each address.

How can I make a formula that can be used across a range of cells i.e all my addresses. I tried dragging over all the cells in the cost per house column  and using formula (example) (`a1:d1(all jobs for address) * a3:d3(all rates for all jobs?)`) then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shft</kbd>+<kbd>entr</kbd> but it didnt work.

Sorry if this is hard to understand. Please ask for any clarification if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:D1,A$3:D$3)
```

Note the use absolute relative references. Those allow the formula remain correct when filled down.

Comment: Yeah, this is correct - I misunderstood. Ben - this is an array formula, but doesn't need to be put in with CSE.